# Documentation structure for web application

Tags: php, documentation

Does anyone know of a decent standard way to structure documentation for a web application using php doc?

I can't really find any examples.

Thanks.

Comment: I am also curious about this, after seeing numerous OSS documentation, seem almost like its application created (by an app) than a person due to the style effort.

Comment: Could you give an example of what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, what I'm trying to figure out if there is some sort of documentation standard. I mean should I be packaging my system documentation based on functionality or should it be packaged using some simple MVC model with subpackages showing the functionality. Or is there a totally different better way to do this I've just missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to do, but there are two things that you can do using php doc.

- Generate HTML/CHM/PDF Api documentations of your app using [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/).
- Embed docbook documentations/tutorials/examples into this api documentation as explained [here](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/phphtmllib/phpDocumentor/tutorial%5Ftutorials.pkg.html).